why Visual editor is disable on wordpress edit post?
I unable to use my visual editor of gutenberg in my wordpress edit post/page. My wordpress installation in under abc.com/resources/ since I am able to use gutenberg visual editor on wordpress installation on abc.com
I have already check the checkbox in profile settings for visual editor.
My hosting is AWS Elasticbeanstalk.
Please let me know the solution for this

Try to deactivate the plugins if any conflicts, Try to switch the theme, verify the permalinks and also check the compatibility of WP version and Plugins.

Hello Mansi
I have checked everything, same code working on main domain abc.com but not working on abc.com/resources/
